# Is there any difference in performance between Database.SqlQuery and EF 6.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two different ways to get data from my SQL database:

```
var sql = @"Select Exam.Name, Test.TestId, Test.QuestionsCount, Test.Title
            FROM Test
            INNER JOIN Exam
               ON ( Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId)
            WHERE Test.TestStatusId = 1";
        var tests1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<TestDTO>(sql).ToList();

        var tests2 = await db.Tests
            .Include(t => t.Exam)
            .Where(t => t.TestStatusId == 1)
            .Select(t => new TestDTO
            {
                ExamName = t.Exam.Name,
                Id = t.TestId,
                QuestionsCount = t.QuestionsCount,
                Title = t.Title
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

I realize the 2nd way seems to be the more "popular" but from a performance point of view is there any difference between the two ways. In particular is it possible to have an async version of the first method or is there likely to be minimal benefit in having that anyway?

Comment: How about trying it in a loop 1000 times with a `Stopwatch` on each iteration? Take the average and decide the winner. Do the same for the async version...

Comment: Considering [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), I would encourage you to make decisions based on functionality, maintainability, and design goals first and performance second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two methods of retrieving data aren't even equal.

In your second method, you are writing an LINQ to Entities query and pulling back a list of Tests that include Exams. Once the query is executed, all of the Tests and Exams will be added to the Entity Framework Change Tracker.

In your first method, you are just using Entity Framework to execute some SQL and convert it to a TestDTO object. None of your entities will be in the change tracker at all.

The first method will probably be faster because you're not involving tracking entities, but they are not really comparable because they are not doing the same thing. Do you plan on making changes to Tests and Exams and calling SaveChanges on the DbContext? If you are then you will doing all of that manually with your first method. I'm not sure why you are asking the question unless you are seeing performance issues with the second query, though. Why not just use a SqlReader or DataAdapter at this point if you don't plan on using EF to even query the data.

Comment: And then there is the [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx), for improving EF performance when no change tracking is required.

Comment: No change tracking needed. I am thinking so far that the 1st method may be easier for maintainability. Would appreciate any additional comments and advice. I do have a context set up for other things in my constructor. What would be the advantage in using SqlReader or DataAdapter? Thanks

Comment: Anne, string query is never more maintainable than linq query - you have compile time syntax check with linq. Also, do not make constructor of EF DbContext make unrelated things - DbContext is supposed to be very lightweight, so you can create and destroy them (by "using" statement) often